# SilverStripe: include_once not working

Tags: php, silverstripe

When I try to install SilverStripe on a server I received a few warnings and errors which were all related to the include_once problem.

I had to replace all include_once in framework/dev/install/DatabaseAdapterRegistry.php and framework/dev/install/install.php5 with include. Only then I could proceed with the installation.

This has never happened before (on other servers) so my question is this: how is it possible that include_once does not include the lib/file but include does?

Is this PHP problem? I have PHP 5.3 and running apache

I also noticed that require_once is not working and that I have to replace it with require... I have stopped with the code modification because there is obviously something very wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

I just tried with the newest SilverStripe (at this point 3.1.9) [installer](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer/) and PHP 5.3.3 and everything worked well. [Requirements](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/getting_started/server_requirements) state that 5.3.2 should be enough but the installer recommended 5.3.4.

The problem is most likely the PHP installation. Also the fact that you have SilverStripe running on other servers points directly to server problems. Search for the differences between the PHP environments/configurations of the working servers and this server.

One thing to note is you shouldn't replace `include_once`/`require_once` without really making sure the files are included/required only once. They are `_once` for a reason...

Could you specify the "`include_once` problem" you are referring to? What error messages you get etc.

Comment: xxxx@xxxx:/usr/bin$ php -v
PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.10 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar 11 2013 14:30:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies

"include_once problem" is that it actauly does not include that file/lib and the errors are different. e.g. warrning: $class variable is not defined which leads to empty database types list etc.
I will try to install a fresh & different version of PHP and report back

Comment: Did you have any success with a fresh installation?

Comment: No success with fresh installation. I think there might be some cache problems because when I simulated the same error on local machine I had to clear cache to resume the normal installation.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following you... How did you simulate the same error? Did clearing the cache help on live environment? Did you try storing the cache in the project directory in `silverstripe-cache` or is it stored in `/tmp`?